Why using compiled code inside compiled code may slow things down?
I made some code that I compiled. The snippet looks as follows:
compiledcode = With[{f1 = function1, f2 = function2, ...}, Hold@Compile[{...},Module[{...},...(*some code involving f1, f2*)...], CompilationTarget -> lang, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}, RuntimeAttributes ->{Listable}]/.DownValues@.../.OwnValues@...//ReleaseHold]

Here, function1, function2 are some other compiled codes, lang is any. I noticed that if making an alternative code, where I explicitly insert function1, function2 inside compiledcode each time when I need to call them instead of using externally, the code works faster (maybe 2 times or so).
Could you please tell me what can be the reason for this? Unfortunately, I was not able to find a minimal example reproducing the issue, but I think that this may be a kind of a generic issue.

Well, when the compiler sees what function1 and function2 actually do (so if gets presented their code), then it can try to inline them and to perform all sorts of optimization. But that really depends on function1 and function2 actually do. So that is hard so say.

Generic (?) MWE:
The inlined version cf1 copies the argument (CopyTensor) of the inlined function; the equivalent coded cf2 does not have this extra copying operation. (Use CompilePrint to examine.)
cf = Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}}, If[Total[x] > 0, Sin[x], Sin[x]]];
cf1 = With[{nestedCF = cf}, Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}}, nestedCF[x],
    CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}]
   ];

cf2 = Compile[ {{x, _Real, 1}}, If[Total[x] > 0, Sin[x], Sin[x]]];

Needs@"CompiledFunctionTools`"

CompilePrint@cf1

CompilePrint@cf2

Example:
data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 10^7];
cf1[data]; // RepeatedTiming
cf2[data]; // RepeatedTiming
(*
{0.0339958, Null}
{0.0277531, Null}
*)

(* cost of CopyTensor: *)
foo = data;
foo[[100]] = 2.; // AbsoluteTiming
(*
{0.00657, Null}
*)

System thresholds can make a big difference:
data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3/2*10^8];
cf1[data]; // RepeatedTiming
cf2[data]; // RepeatedTiming
(*
{0.315479, Null}
{0.255814, Null}
*)

data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 2*^8];
cf1[data]; // RepeatedTiming
cf2[data]; // RepeatedTiming
(*
{2.1032, Null}
{0.339828, Null}
*)

As @Henrik pointed out, just how inlined function calls and code are handled and optimized is probably not as generic as supposed in the OP.

Very good. Indeed, I have also observed in the past that Mathematica somethimes throws in CopyTensor when it "inlines" with "InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True. That's why I would generally discourage the use use of "InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True.

@HenrikSchumacher But what can be an alternative?

Well, when your project needs many compiled functions that have to be called or inlined into each other, and when you are at a point where you spend more time in arm-wrestling Mathematica to generate the right and efficient C code than on developing the actual algorithms..., then you should definitely consider to code directly in C  (or C++) and to use LibraryLink to make the functions callable from Mathematica.
